# String check incorrectly returning true

Tags: batch-file

So I have been playing around in batch trying to make a simple batch game.

So now what have I done wrong?

Here is the code:

```
:promotions_sucessful
cls
if %division%==Bronze V (
set league=Bronze IV
set lp=0
echo You have been promoted!
del promotion.txt
pause>nul
goto menu
)
if %division%==Bronze IV (
set league=Bronze III
set lp=0
echo You have been promoted!
del promotion.txt
pause>nul
goto menu
)
```

So now even if the division is set to Bronze IV it would goto Bronze V why?
Can someone explain what I've done wrong and what I should change. 
I can supply more information if it is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quotes in your `if-statements`:

```
:promotions_sucessful
cls
if "%division%"=="Bronze V" (
set league=Bronze IV
set lp=0
echo You have been promoted!
del promotion.txt
pause>nul
goto menu
)
if "%division%"=="Bronze IV" (
set league=Bronze III
set lp=0
echo You have been promoted!
del promotion.txt
pause>nul
goto menu
)
```

Comment: ...but that particular error was already mentioned in your other post some days ago. This makes people willing to help frustrated.

Comment: Omg, did not notice it the answer i am sorry for taking your guys time